# What is the error for ImageNet "Object localization" challenge?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, computer-vision, object-detection

I have been reading some papers which use the ImageNet-LOC (ImageNet-Localization) dataset. I tried to read up on it to understand what the goal of this dataset is, and hence, what the error we are trying to optimize is.

The official ImageNet 2017 [website](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/index#loc) states that the error we are trying to optimize for **localization** is:

$e=\frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_k min_{i} min_{m}  max \{d(c_i,C_k), f(b_i,B_{km}) \}$

Where the submitter produces 5 class labels $c_i, i = 1, ...5$ in decreasing order of confidence and 5 bounding boxes $b_i, i = 1, ...5$ for each class label. The ground truth labels are $C_k, k = 1, ...n$ with $n$ class labels. For each ground truth class label $C_k$ the ground truth bounding boxes are $B_{km},m=1...M_k$ where $M_k$ is the number of instances of the $k^{th}$ object. $d(c_i, C_k) = 0$ if $c_i = C_k$ and 1 otherwise. $f(b_i, B_k) = 0$ if $b_i$ an $B_k$ have more than $50\%$ overlap and $1$ otherwise.

My interpretation is that it appears that for every ground truth object in an image, we have an error $e_k$ and we **sum up the errors**. The error term **for each ground truth** is 0 if there exists a class label $c_i$ along with a bounding box prediction $b_i$ such that $c_i$ matches that ground truth and $b_i$ matches the ground truth's associated bounding box. This interpretation comes from the fact that we are summing over all k, where k indexes all ground truths.

However, since 2017, ImageNet's dataset along with official specification has moved to [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/imagenet-object-localization-challenge/overview/evaluation). Here, the error for localization seems to be different. Namely:

$e=min_i(min_j(max(d_{ij},f_{ij})))$

Where "$i$ is the predicted labels/bounding boxes, and $j$ is the ground truth labels/bounding boxes." $d$ and $f$ are the same functions as previously stated.

Intuitively, this term seems to try to find **one good match** (first $min$) over **all the ground truths** (second $min$). Effectively, we make a bunch of predictions, but our error only penalizes us if none of them correspond to any ground truth. This seems different than the first error term, where the summation term penalizes errors over all ground truths. Official pseudo-code:

```
min_error_list = []
for prediction_box in [p_0, p_1, p_2]:
    max_error_list = []
    for ground_truth_box in [g_0, g_1]:
        if label(prediction_box) == label(ground_truth_box):
            d = 0
        else:
            d = 1
        if overlap(prediction_box, ground_truth_box) > 0.5:
            f = 0
        else:
            f = 1
        max_error_list.append(max(d,f))   # the first max
    min_error_list.append(min(max_list))  # the first min

return min(min_error_list)  # the second min
```

Thus, my questions are:

Are the two errors different, and if so, why? (Given that the challenge & dataset is the same). An intuitive explanation would be appreciated.